# Linking Html files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link multiple html pages with each other by the use of javascript.

I have a code:

```
    if 
((screen.width>=768) && (screen.height>=1024)) {
    alert('Screen size: 768x1024 or lower');
    $("link[' C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ThemaparkMikuMiku\Website\tabletview.html']");
}
```

but an error comes up saying:

> "uncaught syntax error, unrecognized  expression  ['
>   C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ThemaparkMikuMiku\Website\tabletview.html']

I am also pretty new to javascript though looking alot on the internet, sadly the answer to this question I could never find.

Please help!

Sorry for your time.

I have created 9 html files(3 for tablet, 3 for mobile and 3 for PC version).

I want to link them all together so that if you are with your mobile on the pc version javascript runs a check and loads the mobile version.

I know media queries are there but in my case I thought this was easier..

Comment: what do you mean by "link multiple html pages" ?

Comment: Why do you want to link multiple HTML files?

Comment: For example: 2 html files*  1 html file check if it has the screen size if it has not then load file B I want it to create a responsive design.(i know this can be done with css but I want to do it this way)

Comment: Note that `\tableview` becomes `[tab character]ableview`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but I think you need to escape your backslases '\' -> '\\'

Comment: explain what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? Is it for a responsive design? Because there is a much easier way for it, its called media queries read about it in this article: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I know media queries is easier but I want to do it through javascript.

Comment: 'Why do you want to do that' answers are so frustrating!